# htaccess blocking css and jscript

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

Hi i have my htaccess working, but when i go to https it blocks my scripts and css.
here is a example of the error

```
[blocked] The page at https://bctech.com/checkout.php?session=41fb31bc29722f2e520877d612e0ea4b ran insecure content from http://bctech.com/scripts/superfish.js.
```

Im really at a lost as im new to htacces

here is a example of a css url im useing

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js">
```

and finally here is my attemp at the htaccess file, as i say it works but blocks all my css and jscript files where am i going wrong,, i must be close

.htacces code

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(checkout\.php|final\.php|admin/(.*))$ https://{HTTP_HOST}/$1[R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(checkout\.php|final\.php|admin/(.*))$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# For Sales:

RewriteRule ^shop/sales/?$ sales.php
# For the primary categories:

RewriteRule ^shop/([A-Z-Aa-z\+]+)/?$ shop.php?type=$1
# For specific products:

RewriteRule ^browse/([A-Za-z\+]+)/([A-Za-z\+\-]+)/([0-9]+)$ browse.php?type=$1&category=$2&id=$3
#For https pages:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule here:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(checkout\.php|final\.php|admin/(.*))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Is redirecting HTTPS requests to HTTP, and chrome is probably complaining about it because a secure page (HTTPS) is loading an insecure script (HTTP). Your script is loaded via a URI, so the protocol is HTTPS, and that rule is redirecting it to HTTP. Try adding an exception for css and js to that rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(checkout\.php|final\.php|admin/(.*))$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Jon, Thats works much better, but it is now exposing the $_GET vars on the ends of the urls some how over writing the previous rules like shop/sales and so on. But if i click a link twicw it goes back to normal? if i can stop that im laughing.. But i have clue even where to start as my understanding is still very primative. the only one that doesnt do that is the index.php

Comment: @Brett Move the 2 redirect rules (ones with the `R=301` in the square brackets) **before** all the other rules.

Comment: Does that include the very bottom one for the index? How can i show you what changes i have made?.. and thanks Jon i really appriceiate your help and time. I will edit my question to show you what ive done

Comment: Is that more correct? so do the redirect rules ones with the [R=3o1,L] do they always go before the other rules

Comment: @Brett You can move the redirect from the bottom if you want. That one only matches something very specific. The reason you needed to move them is that 2 rules match the URI, so both rules get applied. Problem is the 2nd rule that gets applied is a redirect, you want to redirect first before the URI gets mangled.